# Different gcc assembly when using designated initializers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm

I was checking some gcc generated assembly for ARM and noticed that I get strange results if I use designated initializers:

E.g. if I have this code:

```
struct test 
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

__attribute__((noinline))
struct test get_struct_1(void)
{
    struct test x;
    x.x = 123456780;
    x.y = 123456781;
    return x;
}

__attribute__((noinline))
struct test get_struct_2(void)
{
    return (struct test){ .x = 123456780, .y = 123456781 };
}
```

I get the [following output](https://godbolt.org/z/nZrmt6) with gcc -O2 -std=C11 for ARM (ARM GCC 6.3.0):

```
get_struct_1:
    ldr r1, .L2
    ldr r2, .L2+4
    stm r0, {r1, r2}
    bx lr
.L2:
    .word 123456780
    .word 123456781


get_struct_2:     // <--- what is happening here
    mov r3, r0
    ldr r2, .L5
    ldm r2, {r0, r1}
    stm r3, {r0, r1}
    mov r0, r3
    bx lr
.L5:
    .word .LANCHOR0
```

I can see the constants for the first function, but I don't understand how `get_struct_2` works.

If I compile for x86, both functions just load the same single 64-bit value in a single instruction.

```
get_struct_1:
    movabs rax, 530242836987890956
    ret

get_struct_2:
    movabs rax, 530242836987890956
    ret
```

Am I provoking some undefined behavior, or is this `.LANCHOR0` somehow related to these constants?

Comment: You did not show `.LANCHOR0` but I assume it has your two constants in it.

Comment: @Jester: that's right, if I turn off "unused labels filtering", I can [find those values](https://godbolt.org/z/LWoaSX) at `.LANCHOR0`. That makes sense, even if I don't understand why the assembly is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like gcc shoots itself in the foot with an extra level of indirection after merging the loads of the constants into an ldm.

No idea why, but pretty obviously a missed optimization bug.

x86-64 is easy to optimize for; the entire 8-byte constant can go in one immediate.  But ARM often uses PC-relative loads for constants that are too big for one immediate.

Comment: Not to mention copying r0 into r3 and back. I wonder if optimization was really enabled for that code as well as the first one. EDIT: yeah it's on ... strange.

Comment: Also, if I just call these functions from `main()` and add their results, gcc will calculate the [compile time constant and return it](https://godbolt.org/z/LR3YlP), so it optimizes it correctly in that case. Perhaps I can report this somewhere to be fixed in future versions. Thanks!

Comment: @Lou: yes, report at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ and use the "missed-optimization" keyword.  It's no surprise that constant-propagation still works, but yeah it's good to know the scope of this bug is limited.